# Error while sending json to elastic search , when i dumps json of error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am uploading data to elastic search server by sending josn to elastic search, it is working fine but on some characters like \ it gives error , when i send backslash in json , & if i dump the json of response it gives error

```
"{"error": {"caused_by": {"reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes", "type": "not_x_content_exception"}, "reason": "failed to parse", "root_cause": [{"reason": "failed to parse", "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"}], "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"}, "status": 400}"
```

my josn string is ,

```
"{

"first_name":"muhammad irfan",

"middle_name": "",

"last_name":"ulhaq choudhary",

"address":"H,no,197,St,no. 157. G-9\\4",

"city":"Islamabad",

"phone_number1":"",

"phone_number2":"",

"phone_number3":"",

"gender":"M",

"updation_time":"0000-01-01",

"country_id":"1"
}
"
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/21440

Comment: Your json is valid, looks like a bug with the Elasticsearch. What elastic search version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which package you use.
But you can try `\\\\` instead of `\\`.